# Expo uncaugh error : The snack @snack/sdk.32.0.0 was found

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to run the reactnative code example (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial) on my device using expo but giving error :-

```
Uncaught Error: The snack "@snack/sdk.32.0.0-VADy5rsVI"
was found, but wasn't released for platform "android" and
sdk version "32.0.0".
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Update your expo client, your phone has updated to the new android version.

Comment: Why was this answer so wrong? It's actually a valid response. Could someone explain why it took so many downvotes?

Comment: I've updated the latest version

Comment: Updating the "Expo Go" app fixed the issue for me as well :)