# Error with sdk 46.0.0 (@snack/sdk.46.0.0) on android device with newly installed Expo Go

Tags: android, react-native, expo

My situation is as follows:

- SDK Version: 46.0.0
- Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android (9 PKQ1.180904.001 (MIUI Global 11.0.3.0(PEIMIXM)))
- Add the appropriate “Tag” based on what Expo library you have a question on: no clue.
- React Native version: no clue, but it should be the latest on the post's date

I’ve just signed up at [expo.dev](https://expo.dev/) and installed the Expo Go app on my android phone (Xiaomi Redmi Note 5). At the time there were no updates for the phone’s OS. Custom firmware wasn’t installed as well.
Now I’m trying to launch standard Hello World from the official React Native Introduction ([Introduction · React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started)).

Sadly, instead of a “Hello World” message, I see this:

**The snack “@snack/sdk.46.0.0-peNxQR0YAV” was found, but wasn’t released for platform “android” and SDK version “46.0.0”**

And it seems there is not much I can try out to get rid of this error.

There is a similar question: [Expo uncaugh error : The snack @snack/sdk.32.0.0 was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286851/expo-uncaugh-error-the-snack-snack-sdk-32-0-0-was-found)
But the only answer is advice to update Expo Go, which is obviously not the proper case for the newly installed app.

So here is a logical question: How should I get rid of that error?

Comment: need more details about your android version and react native version

Comment: @UshanFernando, I've provided detailed Android version, but no idea how to see used react native version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expo Go for Android does not currently support Expo v46. To fix this go to your snack and at the bottom right change the expo version to v45.

It will ask you to restart Expo Go on your phone. Once you have done that it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ravi. Actually, I didn't install snack explicitly. So I don't know how to go in there. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Ah, that is actually not in the phone. And that’s what people forget to mention )). So to make it clear to other wondering people, i’ll clarify it myself. Nevertheless, I'll mark Ravi's answer as solving one

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. It didn't work for me with Expo v45 either, but in the dropdown v47 was available as well. Switching to that version did work for me.

Comment: Don't quiet follow how to make Hello World example run. Which dropdown? i only see Supported Versions 47,48,49 in my Samsung phone settings for latest Expo Client version 2.29.3 (on the Settings page of Expo).
When i scan the QR code on the official docs, i get the same kinda message "wasn't release for platform 43.0.0".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ravi's answer above I'll clarify, where exactly snack sdk version should be changed.

When you read documentation and see a code example block, you should first switch to the full-window editing mode using the second button of the code example block caption [image: button] next to the example title. After you will get to the full-window editing mode, you should see there the dropdown menu in the right bottom corner where you should choose another version of sdk (45.0.0 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Expo Go 2.25.1 support sdk46 and it is available. But I think it not yet updated on google play store. So the solution is to let expo install the lastest version on expo go for you.

1. Uninstall the expo Go you downloaded from app store
2. Enable android developer option on your phone (if your are using a physical device and if you didn't do it before [check here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/junk-email-reporting-addin-for-microsoft-outlook-2010/))
3. connect your phone with the your computer using a usb cable
4. go to your project and start it with `expo start --android`

it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expo Go 2.25.1 support sdk46 and it is available. But I think it not yet updated on google play store.

Follow https://expo.dev/tools and download the Android.apk archive

Install this apk on your phone and sdk 46 you have

It worked for me, cheers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9jsE.png)

https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-46-c2a1655f63f7

> **Note:** **Expo Go for Android with support for SDK 46 is not yet live on
> the Google Play Store** — it is currently in review and expected to be
> released soon. You can install the latest Expo Go by **downloading the
> APK directly** or connecting your device to your computer and letting
> Expo CLI install it when you launch your project. While we are waiting
> for the app to be released to the store, projects created with npx
> create-expo-app will default to SDK 45. You can create a new SDK 46
> project by running npx create-expo-app --template blank@sdk-46